# Is my Mac Mini's fan okay?

Tags: hardware, mac-mini, temperature

I replaced the HDD with a hybrid HDD/SSD about a week ago, following iFixit's guide for doing so. However, when putting it back together, I stripped one of the connectors on the fan.

My Mini gets really hot, so it makes me think the fan isn't working all the way, if at all. At the same time, my office doesn't have insulation (and it's on the second floor of my apartment) so it gets really hot. I have a fan on now, facing me and the Mini and it feels better, just a bit warm.

I just want to know if I am stressing too much, or if there is reason for concern.

Comment: you should be able to hear the fan if it is working.

Comment: @Buscar웃SD I actually *don't* hear the fan. This worries me.

Comment: you should not run at all without the fan working, more serious damage can happen. Replace the fan.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the model year of the Mac mini, you could run Apples hardware diagnostics if supported.

Shutdown your Mac mini.  Turn back on and press and hold the keys: option + D during the grey screen before the Apple logo.

If asked join a network and let it boot into the Apple hardware test.  This will tell you if the fan is reporting an error along with other hardware tests.

Comment: I actually took it to an Apple store earlier this week and they did that test. Nothing about the fan came up.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I'd probably just replace the fan, it's typically relatively cheap and the first thing to come out of most (maybe even all) Mac Minis.

Comment: The connector thing that the fan plugs into is off the board. I suppose I could solder it back?

Comment: I wouldn't. Unless you have a lot of experience with computer soldering, I'd pay a pro to do it. But if you can hear your fan, you're probably alright, just monitor it closely when in use.

Comment: Wait, did you say it's completely fallen off of the board?

Comment: It's not completely off the board, just *one* of the connectors is off. There are four other connectors that are still in place.

Comment: Well, as long as you can hear it, I think you're okay. Just monitor it.